# Turn a class ID into an variable in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, variables

How can I made the ID of an div class/id in HTML into a variable in Java/jQuery?

So say for example I have the code below

```
<div id="wrapper">

    <div id="slider">

    <div class="slide" id="slide1ID"> <a href="link"> <img src="imglink"> 

                 </a>   
    </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

How would I reference the id of "slide1ID" in jQuery? Would it be something similar to this?

```
var ID-of-Slide = 'id=slide1ID'
```

Comment: "ID-of-Slide" I don't think you can declare a variable like that in jQuery/javascript

Comment: @Myth Then how to declare variable in jQuery?

Comment: @Anup I think "var ID-of-Slide = 'id=slide1ID'" will surely throw an error

Comment: @Myth Yes..you are correct...http://jsfiddle.net/GNHJc/1/

Comment: This is why I was asking!

Comment: @CameoCream Simply change the variable name... http://jsfiddle.net/GNHJc/2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
var ID-of-Slide = $('.slide').attr('id');
```

or more specific:

```
var ID-of-Slide = $('#wrapper .slide').attr('id');
```

Update:

You can use [map()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) to get an array of ids when you have multiple classes of `slide`:

```
var idArray = $("#wrapper .slide").map(function() { return this.id; }).get();
```

Comment: Say if I had multiple classes of 'slide' would those two still work?

Comment: @CameoCream No, it's not, if you want to get all ids from multiple classes of 'slide', you'll need to loop through them using `$.each('.slide')` and push those ids to the expected array.

Comment: So I would use something like var ID-of-Slide = $.each('.slide').attr('id')

Comment: @CameoCream Oh .. is it really working for you.. or showing an error at variable declaration

Comment: @Felix `var ID-of-Slide` this variable name isn't going to work.

Comment: I know the variable name won't work, it was just an example. I'll give this a go. You think you could make a quick fiddle for me?

Comment: Perfect! So I would substitute a 0,1,2 when I want to call to a specific id in a string of code?

Comment: Thank you very much, this was very very helpful! Now I just gotta get it to work with the rest of the code! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Try this :-

```
var IDofSlide = $("#slide1ID").attr("id");
```

Comment: is it possible to declare a variable like.. "ID-of-Slide"

Comment: @myth you are talking abt variable name...Good observation +1

Comment: its just to understand so ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

Simple:- jst try or check this http://jsfiddle.net/NPhx4/3/

```
var ID-of-Slide = $(".slide").attr("id");
```

Comment: @MaTya Where is the button value in fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `javascript`

```
 var Id= document.getElementById("slide1ID").id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
var ID-of-Slide= $('#slide1ID').attr('id');
alert(ID-of-Slide);
```